# Deploy Application to AWS EC2 Instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I need to deploy my Java application to AWS EC2 Instance using terraform. **The catch here, we should not use *.pem file to deploy the application**.

I try to create ELB and associate instances using terraform.I can able to deploy the application using ssh and pem file to ec2 instances Private IPs. But we shouldn't use *.pem or *.ppk file, as it'll not be allowed in production servers.

I tried using chef with terraform , but that also requires *.pem to connect to AWS Instances.

Please let me know the detailed steps/suggestions of how to deploy the application using terraform without using pem file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't make any changes to your instance after creating it (including deploying the application) then you will need to bake any and all changes into the AMI that Terraform deploys.

You might want to look into using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) to create AMIs with your intended configuration and then use Terraform to deploy these AMIs.

For reference, this strategy is known as "immutable infrastructure" so you might want to do some further reading into this area.

If instead it's simply that SSH connectivity is not allowed and you can make changes over other ports then you should be able to use an AMI that has a [Chef](https://www.chef.io/) client, [Puppet](https://puppet.com) agent or [Salt](https://saltstack.com/) minion on it (there may well be other tools that work over a non SSH protocol/port but this restriction rules out [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)) and then use any of those tools to continue to configure your instance. Obviously you could find a suitable AMI from the AMI marketplace or, once again, use Packer to set up the relevant configuration management client.